# Google Chrome - Saved Passwords won't work in Incognito

Tags: google-chrome, browser, password-protection

Post version 18 of Google Chrome, the saved passwords are not working in incognito mode,

I have all my passwords saved within Google chrome. When I go to any login page with saved passwords, for instance Gmail login; using the normal Google chrome mode, The Passwords are auto-filled.

However if I am using Incognito mode, the passwords wont be auto-filled, forcing me to type them.

I am webmaster, having many cPanel passwords stored which i don't wanna type again n again since they are long-complicated, and typing passwords may be vulnerable to key-loggers !!

Does anyone know any workout to this, or probably a hack to the Chrome browser to force it filling Passwords in incognito mode!

Comment: You should consider switching to a 3rd-party password manager like LastPass or 1Password. They don't care about browser mode and provide an extra layer of security since browsers don't encrypt stored passwords.

Comment: @dnbrv No doubt your suggestion is bright, however since long I am synchronizing all my passwords and other stuff using the google account (chrome sync). At this point of time i am not willing to start everything afresh.

Comment: Funny. The majority of password managers can easily import all of your passwords stored in any browser on your computer (just like a malicious scraper can). Moreover, they all can be synced easily.

Comment: Did you even bother looking at either of the services I mentioned? LastPass is 100% cloud & 1Password can be synced with Dropbox or anything similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Chromium (reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117720)), which will be fixed in the next version.

You can either downgrade to Chrome 18 or upgrade to [Chrome 20 beta](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/).

Comment: UPDATE : Chrome 20 Stable has been released... This problem has been resolved and passwords do get auto-filled, however one needs to enter the exact username first and then tab key to get the passwords auto-filled.

Comment: This question may now be marked as closed if the moderators deem to, considered someone else may not face the same problem in V20 or above in future!!